# C++ brace initializer as an argument calls different constructor then expected

Tags: c++

Minimal example is such class:

```
class Chain {
    public:
        Chain(std::string name, std::vector<int> args)
        {
            assert(true);
        }
        Chain(std::string name, bool flag)
        {
            assert(false);
        }
};
```

with usage as such

```
int main() {
    auto ch = Chain("name", {});
    return 1;
}
```

The second constructor of `Chain` didn't have the `bool flag` before, I had to add it and now the code `Chain("name", {})` calls the second constructor (before it called the first one).

I thought I will change the order of arguments of the second constructor

```
        Chain(bool flag, std::string name)
        {
            assert(false);
        }
```

but even then it rather casts `const char *` to `bool` and `{}` to `std::string` then to call the first constructor.

Is there a way to forbid it/force the usage to call the first ctor?

Comment: IMHO, this example should convince you that these two functions should not be overloaded with each other.

Comment: @Brian true, I've already changed the second constructor to static method `Chain parse_from_string(string, bool)` which even makes more sense (in the whole program context), still I was curios if there's another way

Comment: How about using `enum class` instead of the `bool`? Would even make it obvious what it means (what true means? what false means? `ChainFlag::DoThat` is better.)

Comment: @firda also true, will refactor it further ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[overload resolution rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution) are complex:

Any of following overloads is viable:

```
Chain(std::string name, std::vector<int> args); #1
Chain(std::string name, bool flag); #2a
Chain(bool flag, std::string name); #2b
```

for

```
Chain("name", {});
```

but both `#2a` and `#2b` are best candidate than `#1` especially for the reason:

> 1) A standard conversion sequence is always better than a user-defined conversion sequence or an ellipsis conversion sequence.

so `{} -> bool` is better than `{} -> std::vector<int>` and
`const char* -> bool` is better than `const char* -> std::string`
(and `{} -> std::vector<int>` is equivalent to `{} -> std::string`).

I suggest to add a wrapper class around `bool`, something like:

```
struct bool_wrapper
{
    // bool_wrapper() : b(false) {} // would make your call ambiguous.
    bool_wrapper(bool b) : b(b) {}

    operator bool() const {return b;}

    bool b = false;  
};
```

And then

```
Chain(std::string name, bool_wrapper flag); // To fix overload resolution
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9b59ba8c93bdf7b5)
[Demo with ambiguous call](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/37dd4277e5ddb8ff)

Comment: thanks for doc and better explanation, even the bool wrapper I like more then other proposed solutions.

Answer (score 3):

Use the explicit type.

```
auto ch1 = Chain("name", std::vector<int>{});
auto ch2 = Chain("name", true);
```

Comment: well for sure this will work, but consider my case: I added new constructor to a class that is already used on several places in the project, these ctors are totaly different (considering the case where the second ctor is even `(bool, string)`) and yet compiler chooses differently than I'd ever expected, so I'm looking for a way to forbid it (maybe in the future)

Comment: @sejvlond, *so I'm looking for a way to forbid it* The surest way to ascertain that will be to use explicitly typed arguments. Use of implicitly converted arguments are fraught with the pitfall that you are experiencing now.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't modify calls to the first constructor like `Chain("name", std::vector<int>{});`, I can advice two ways.

If calls to the first constructor are always performed with string literals like "name" (not std::string), then you can modify the both constructors:

```cpp
class Chain {
    public:
        Chain(const char* name, std::vector<int> args)
        {
            assert(true);
        }
        Chain(bool flag, const std::string& name)
        {
            assert(false);
        }
};
```

If the above assumption is false, then you can add dummy parameter to the second constructor:

```cpp
class Chain {
    public:
        Chain(std::string name, std::vector<int> args)
        {
            assert(true);
        }
        Chain(std::string name, bool flag, bool dummy)
        {
            assert(false);
        }
};
```

And the bonus solution that does not require modifications of the constructors:

```cpp
class Chain {
    public:
        Chain(const std::string& name, std::vector<int> args)
        {
            assert(true);
        }
        template<typename T>
        Chain(const std::string& name, T flag);
};

template<>
Chain::Chain(const std::string& name, bool flag)
{
    assert(false);
}
```